# Consume The Changes / Deltas using Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, upsert

Following is my scenario:

I have 2 landing tables source_table and destination_table.

I need a query/queries which will update the destination table with the new rows as well as the updated rows from source table.

Sample Data would be:

```
source table:
id    name    salary
1     P1      10000
2     P2      20000

target table:
id    name    salary
1     P1      8000
```

And the expected output should be:

```
target table:
id    name    salary
1     P1      10000 (salary updated)
2     P2      20000 (new row inserted)
```

This doesn't seem to work:

```
select * from user_source 
except 
select * from user_target as s

INSERT INTO user_target (id, name, salary) 
VALUES (s.id, s.name, s.salary) WHERE id !=s.id

UPDATE user_target 
  SET name=s.name, salary=s.salary,
WHERE id = s.id
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a simple [`insert ... on conflict`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) to me:

```
insert into target_table (id, name, salary)
select id, name, salary 
from source_table
on conflict (id) do update 
  set name = excluded.name, 
      salary = excluded.salary;
```

This assumes that the `id` column is the primary (or unique) key. Looking at the sample data `(id, name)` might also be unique. In that case you need to change the `on conflict()` clause and obviously remove the update of the name column as well.